# Export not found on module

Tags: typescript, babeljs, rollup

I have a library, in one of the files i export an interface:

```
export interface MyInterface {
...
}
```

and there is a default export, which is a react component.

On an `index.ts` file, I import few stuff, and re-export them:

```
import Something from "./Something";
import OtherStuff from "./OtherStuff";
import ExportDefault, { MyInterface } from "./QuestionFile";

export { Something, OtherStuff, ExportDefault, MyInterface };
```

When I compile, I get an error:

> MyInterface is not exported by QuestionFile.

My goal is, whoever imports my library is able to import that type definition to use too.

Is there a better way to do that?

if I do:

`export * from "./QuestionFile"`

it works, otherwise it breaks my build.

An example on what is going on can be found on this repository: https://github.com/PlayMa256/typescript-babel-error

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Re-exporting types is one of the known TypeScript constructs that don't work when using Babel to compile TypeScript because they require cross-file information.  You can enable the `isolatedModules` TypeScript compiler option to report these constructs as errors when you compile with `tsc` (not Babel) or use the TypeScript language service in an IDE.  `export *` is one workaround; another described in [this issue](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/603) is to use a type alias instead of a re-export.  Yet another workaround is to merge a constant with the interface.  (It's a hack but avoids some of the disadvantages of the other approaches.)

```
export interface testInterface {
    name?: string;
}
export const testInterface = undefined;
```

Answer (score 5):

From https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/:

> As a solution in TypeScript 3.8, we’ve added a new syntax for type-only imports and exports.

```
import type { SomeThing } from "./some-module.js";

export type { SomeThing };
```